# Understanding the sed N command

Tags: linux, sed

The sed manual states about the N command:

> N

> Add a newline to the pattern space, then append the next line of input to the pattern space. If there is no more input then sed exits without processing any more commands.

Now, from what I know, sed reads each line of input, applies the script(s) on it, and (if -n is not specified) prints it as the output stream.

So, given the following example file:

```
Apple
Banana
Grapes
Melon
```

Running this:

```
$ sed '/Banana/N;p'
```

From what I understand, sed should process each line of input: Apple, Banana, Grapes and Melon.
So, I would think that the output will be:

```
Apple
Apple
Banana
Grapes # since it read the next line with N
Banana
Grapes
Grapes (!)
Grapes (!)
Melon
Melon
```

Explanation:
`Apple` is read to the pattern space. it doesn't match `Banana` regex, so only `p` is applied. It's printed twice: once for the `p` command, and once because sed prints the pattern space by default.
Next, `Banana` is read to the pattern space. It matches the regex, so that the N command is applied: so it reads the next line `Grapes` to the pattern space, and then `p` prints it: `Banana\nGrapes`. Next, the pattern space is printed again due to the default behavior.

Now, I would expect that `Grapes` will be read to the pattern space, so that `Grapes` will be printed twice, same as for Apple and Melon.

But in reality, this is what I get:

```
Apple
Apple
Banana
Grapes
Banana
Grapes
Melon
Melon
```

It seems that once `Grapes` was read as part of the N command that was applied to `Banana`, it will no longer be read as a line of its own.

Is that so? and if so, why isn't it emphasized in the docs?

Comment: `sed` reads each record only once. So, after `Grapes`has been read by the `N` command the next record is not `Grapes` again, it's `Melon`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might explain it (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Banana/N;p' file --d
SED PROGRAM:
/Banana/ N
p
INPUT:   'file' line 1
PATTERN: Apple
COMMAND: /Banana/ N
COMMAND: p
Apple
END-OF-CYCLE:
Apple
INPUT:   'file' line 2
PATTERN: Banana
COMMAND: /Banana/ N
PATTERN: Banana\nGrapes
COMMAND: p
Banana
Grapes
END-OF-CYCLE:
Banana
Grapes
INPUT:   'file' line 4
PATTERN: Melon
COMMAND: /Banana/ N
COMMAND: p
Melon
END-OF-CYCLE:
Melon
```

Where `--d` is short for `--debug`

You will see the `INPUT:` lines go `1,2,4` because the second cycle also grabs input line 3 with the `N` command.

Answer (score 0):

To debug this, I added `=` to your script so that you can see what's being emitted at each iteration. The line numbers conveniently demarcate the output from each. Then to identify the default print action at the end of each iteration, I added `s/.*/==&==/` so you can see what was printed by `sed` because you did not specify `-n`.

```
sed '/Banana/N;=;p;=;s/.*/==&==/' <<\:
> Apple
> Banana
> Grapes
> Melon
> :
1
Apple
1
==Apple==
3
Banana
Grapes
3
==Banana
Grapes==
4
Melon
4
==Melon==
```

So, the pattern space containing `Banana` and `Grapes` was printed twice, and the first and last lines were printed in isolation twice.

Comment: Not sure your explanation is correct. From GNU `sed` info: _Unless special commands (like ‘D’) are used, the pattern space is deleted between two cycles_. So, as far as I understand the sed algorithm, the `N` action is not _taken again_. The `Banana\nGrapes` pattern space is printed twice and the next cycle starts with an empty pattern space. As `Grapes` has already been read the next line is `Melon`, reason why `Grapes` is not printed 4 times as the OP expect but only 2. Note that this explanation also matches your output with `=`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Thanks for prodding; you were absolutely right - updated the answer. I came up with a better debugging effort which shows exactly what's going on.